# Scala : Template testing with Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am transitioning from Java to Scala. I am looking for a way to do test similar as :

```
//As a template is a just a method, you can execute it from a test and check the result:

@Test
public void renderTemplate() {
  Content html = views.html.index.render("Welcome to Play!");
  assertEquals("text/html", html.contentType());
  assertTrue(contentAsString(html).contains("Welcome to Play!"));
}
```

I found it here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaTest
Any attempts to find this in documentation to follow to write similar test in scala have failed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of tests called [Functional Tests](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaFunctionalTest) in PlayFramework
Yes, there are well documented samples for writing functional tests as well as testing templates. The following code sample is alternative version in Scala

```scala
"render index template" in {
  val html = views.html.index("Hello")

  contentType(html) must equalTo("text/html")
  contentAsString(html) must contain("Welcome to Play!")
}
```

Example2. Testing the router:

```scala
"respond to the index Action" in {
  val Some(result) = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(GET, "/Bob"))

  status(result) must equalTo(OK)
  contentType(result) must beSome("text/html")
  charset(result) must beSome("utf-8")
  contentAsString(result) must contain("Hello Bob")
}
```